# Android Cursor trying to read data from table - Nullpointer exception thrown

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Searched a whole bunch of the same question and i couldn't get an idea why i get NPE. Pls help.

My code to read data from a table is,

```
private String []cols = {"name","id"};

public void seeRecord(String a, int b){



    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from vijay", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
    String nameintable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cols[0]));

    int idintable = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(cols[1]));

    a=nameintable;
    b=idintable;

}
    c.close();
}
```

**To insert data to the table is:**

```
public void addRecord(String name, int id){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name",name);
    values.put("id", id);

    db.insert("vijay", null, values);
    db.close();
    }
```

logcat errors:

```
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at com.example.databaseaccess.MainActivity.see(MainActivity.java:42)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    ... 11 more
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    at com.example.databaseaccess.DbHelper.seeRecord(DbHelper.java:61)
07-30 12:11:34.755: E/AndroidRuntime(15894):    ... 15 more
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at com.example.databaseaccess.MainActivity.see(MainActivity.java:42)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    ... 11 more
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    at com.example.databaseaccess.DbHelper.seeRecord(DbHelper.java:61)
07-30 12:23:40.606: E/AndroidRuntime(18817):    ... 15 more
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at com.example.databaseaccess.MainActivity.see(MainActivity.java:42)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    ... 11 more
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1333)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    at com.example.databaseaccess.DbHelper.seeRecord(DbHelper.java:61)
07-30 12:23:49.245: E/AndroidRuntime(18861):    ... 15 more
```

both are called in onclick event of a button. Inserting works properly. But when clicking read button, app crashes.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: `at com.example.databaseaccess.DbHelper.seeRecord(DbHelper.java:61)` There is an object at line 61 which is null. Please find this line yourself and debug to see what object is null

Comment: while(c.moveToNext()) is that line pal. Does that mean there is nothing in the db stored?

Comment: No, `moveToNext()` returns boolean value so It will never be null. I guess that C instance is null. Please check if you opened Database successful. In the case you have no records, `c.moveToNext()` just returns false.

Comment: now the app don't crash. but the value returned is, '0.null'. So no records in table (or) mistake in reading?

Comment: Please try my solution at below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use this way:

```
public List<Ticket> getTickets() {
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from ABC" , null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            //parse data here
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return tickets;
    }
```

In the case above codes don't fix your problem, please try this:

```
public List<Ticket> getTickets() {
    openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from ABC" , null);
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        //parse data here
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return tickets;
}
```

Comment: Now its working pal. Thank you so much. But it just shows the just entered value. How to retrieve those already saved?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public void seeRecord(String a, int b){

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from vijay", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String nameintable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cols[0]));

        int idintable = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(cols[1]));

        a=nameintable;
        b=idintable;

    }
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: This is how it looks now. App doesn't crash but returns "0. null" as the value.

Comment: are you sure there is at least 1 record at `vijay` table?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh: How to check that? If the insert function works properly, there should be a lot of records in it.

Comment: No Asha. Just displaying what we just entered into db. Or displays null,0.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public void seeRecord(String a, int b){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from vijay", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
    String nameintable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cols[0]));

    int idintable = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(cols[1]));

    a=nameintable;
    b=idintable;
   }
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: didn't work yet pal. app crashes. i suspect cursor part to be the place where the mistake lies.

Comment: Tried pal. returned 0.null

Comment: @VijayaRagavan here is 
    a=nameintable;
    b=idintable; something wrong ! try by testing Log.d("test",nameintable+" "+idintable);

Answer (score 1):

You might want to post the logcat to make this debug easier. But based off that code I'm assuming your db is null.

In your insert you call these 2 methods.

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();

db.close();
```

I'm assumming it's crashing on this line.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from vijay", null);
```

Which means you will need to reopen /close the database like you did in the insert.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace your code with this**

```
public Cursor seeRecord()
{
    db.open(); 
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from vijay", null);
    db.close();

    return c;
}
```

write following code on your method where you want to upadte your view

```
db.open(); 
Cursor c = seeRecord();

 c.moveToFirst();

while(!c.isAfterLast())
{
    if(c != null)
    {
        String nameintable = c.getString(0);
        int idintable = c.getInt(1);

        Your_View.id.setText(nameintable);
        Your_View.id.setText(idintable);
    }
    c.moveToNext();
}
c.close();  
db.close();
```

Comment: Sorry David. App crashes.

Comment: No i didn't. carelesness. Now after inserting that, null value is returned. That too the initialized values of the variables where the values from the cursor is stored.

Comment: It ain't david. I initialized some two variables to be null and 0. The values got from the cursor is stored to these variables. And the textview is updated with these variable values.

Comment: But instead of the values returned from the cursor getting printed, the default assigned values are printed. that means no values returned from the cursor?

Comment: you can handle this null or 0 by if condition.